# how to keep CPU usage level low using javascript function

Tags: javascript, cpu-usage

I am trying to develop my apps in Javascript.

I have one function that consumes too much CPU power.
I would like to know a way to control this by code (not with any external application) and restrict the percentage of CPU usage. For example, if it uses 90% of the CPU usage, to make my app consume only a 20%, even if it becomes slower.

It must be done automatically and from within the app. 
If you could provide any function, it would be fantastic.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to improve functions, but without the function itself I don't think we could do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is improve the function so it's faster.

JavaScript does not allow CPU-throttling.

Comment: @LightStyle:Can you send me the sample code for reducing CPU usage using Javascript.......